# Ajax/jQuery success -> show as html markup

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, markup

Right now I have 2 php pages.

Page 1 has a function in which an AJAX call is being done.
On success, I want to show the result in a specific span with id omschrijving.

The code:

```
  function toonProfiel() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./query/get.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (value) {
      alert (value.omschrijving);
      $("#omschrijving").html(value.omschrijving);
    }
    });
  }
```

Ofcourse, I also have the get.php page, which looks like this (simplified):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT omschrijving FROM leden")) {

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($omschrijving);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    $value= array(
      'omschrijving' => $omschrijving
    );

    echo json_encode($value);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Now when I alert the value.omschrijving, the markup is still fine.
Apparently it's saved correct in mySQL and also retrieved in the correct format.

But, ofcourse, when I use the function .html(value.omschrijving), it's not in html format, so it's just 1 long string.

It will look like this: this is line 1. this is line 2.

HTML FORMAT (quotes are showing up in developer tools but not on page and the blank rule is there but not on the page):

```
<span id="omschrijving">
"this is line 1.

this is line 2."
</span>
```

I want to keep/add the html format, so that it will display like this:

this is line 1.

this is line 2.

Is this possible?

Comment: please show the returned html

Comment: Nick, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

"span" tags are used to display "inline" elements. Your text is wrapped in a single span tag, therefore it is displayed on one line. There are many ways to insert line breaks, you can wrap each line inside a "p" or "div" tag, or simply insert a line break "br" where you wish. Your code is working like it supposed to, as long as you aren't actually seeing the html tags. Even though your html looks like this:

```
    <span id="omschrijving">
    "this is line 1.

     this is line 2."
    </span>
```

in your code editor, the **whitespace and line breaks are not automagically preserved** without using "& nbsp;" or line break tags. You can also take a look at the CSS **white-space** property if you do not wish to use ampersand notation or line break tags.

Answer (score -1):

Are your text strings broken by newlines? That would explain why they look fine in MySQL and not in HTML

Try:

```
function (value) {
  value.split("\n").map(function(n,i){return "<p>"+n+"</p>";}).join("\n");
  alert (value.omschrijving);
  $("#omschrijving").html(value.omschrijving);
}
```

That will split on the new lines, then wrap each line in < p> tags, then rejoin with a newline between each line, just for readability.

Comment: Why the down vote? This solution will work and the poster is clearly using jQuery in his question.